SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from <LINK>
I need help with this code I'm writing for GNRE in Espirito Santo, using the SOAP standard (version 1.2), I'm programming in PHP (version 7.2.24), and it's giving this error: SOAP Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL : Couldn't load from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' : failed to load external entity "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" follows the code:
    <?php

function verifyRequiredExtensions() {
    $extensions = ['soap', 'openssl', 'xml'];
    foreach ($extensions as $ext) {
        if (!extension_loaded($ext)) {
            die("E01 PHP extension $ext not installed.");
        }
    }
}

function validateParameters($argc, $argv) {
    if ($argc != 5) {
        die("E01 Incorrect parameters for execution: php {$argv[0]} <action> <xml_file> <pfx_certificate> <password>");
    }

    $action = $argv[1];
    if (!in_array($action, ['emission', 'pdf'])) {
        die("E01 Invalid action: $action");
    }

    return $action;
}

function validateFiles($xmlFile, $certFile, $caCert) {
    if (!file_exists($xmlFile)) {
        die("E01 XML file not found: $xmlFile");
    }

    if (!is_readable($xmlFile)) {
        die("E01 XML file not readable: $xmlFile");
    }

    if (!file_exists($certFile)) {
        die("E01 Certificate not found: $certFile");
    }

    if (!is_readable($certFile)) {
        die("E01 Certificate not readable: $certFile");
    }

    if (!file_exists($caCert)) {
        die("E01 CA certificate not found: $caCert");
    }

    if (!is_readable($caCert)) {
        die("E01 CA certificate not readable: $caCert");
    }
}

function createSSLContext($caCert) {
    return stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'verify_peer_name' => true,
            'allow_self_signed' => false,
            'cafile' => $caCert,
            'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
        ]
    ]);
}

function configureSOAPClient($certFile, $certPassword, $sslContext) {
    return [
        'local_cert' => $certFile,
        'passphrase' => $certPassword,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'trace' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'stream_context' => $sslContext,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout' => 60,
        'exceptions' => true
    ];
}

function processSOAPResponse($client, $xmlFile) {
    try {
        // Reads the content of the XML file
        $xmlContent = file_get_contents($xmlFile);

        // Prepares the SOAP message body
        $params = [
            'duaDadosMsg' => $xmlContent
        ];

        // Sends the request
        $response = $client->duaObterPdf($params);

        // Processes the response
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($client->__getLastResponse());
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('duae', 'http://www.sefaz.es.gov.br/duae');

        // Extracts relevant fields
        $return = $xml->xpath('//duae:retObterPdfDua')[0];
        $cStat = (string)$return->cStat;
        $xMotivo = (string)$return->xMotivo;

        if ($cStat != '106') {
            die("E01 Unable to obtain PDF of DUA. cStat: $cStat - Reason: $xMotivo");
        }

        // Extracts and saves the PDF
        $pdfBase64 = (string)$return->xPdf;
        $pdfContent = base64_decode($pdfBase64);

        // Generates the output file name
        $outputFile = dirname($xmlFile) . '/' . basename($xmlFile, '.xml') . '.pdf';

        if (file_put_contents($outputFile, $pdfContent) === false) {
            die("E01 Unable to save PDF file of DUA: $outputFile");
        }

        echo "PDF of DUA successfully saved in: $outputFile";
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        $message = "E01 SOAP service failure: " . $e->getMessage() . " Last request: " . (isset($client) ? $client->__getLastRequest() : '');
        logError($message, $xmlFile);
        die("$message");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = "E01 General failure: " . $e->getMessage();
        logError($message, $xmlFile);
        die("$message");
    }
}

function logError($message, $xmlFile) {
    // Generates the output file name
    $logFile = dirname($xmlFile) . '/' . basename($xmlFile, '.xml') . '.log';
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    file_put_contents($logFile, "[$timestamp] $message\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

// Script Start
verifyRequiredExtensions();

$action = validateParameters($argc, $argv);
$xmlFile = $argv[2];
$certFile = $argv[3];
$certPassword = $argv[4];

// Adjust relative path
if (substr($certFile, 0, 2) == '..') {
    $certFile = '/var/www' . substr($certFile, 2);
}
$certFile = str_replace('//', '/', $certFile);

$caCert = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt';

validateFiles($xmlFile, $certFile, $caCert);

$sslContext = createSSLContext($caCert);
$options = configureSOAPClient($certFile, $certPassword, $sslContext);

try {
    // Define WSDL
    $wsdl = 'https://app.sefaz.es.gov.br/WsDua/DuaService.asmx?wsdl';

    // Create SOAP client
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    // Prepare SOAP header
    $header = new SoapHeader(
        'http://www.sefaz.es.gov.br/duae',
        'duaServiceHeader',
        ['versao' => '1.01']
    );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    processSOAPResponse($client, $xmlFile);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = "E01 Failed to configure SOAP client: " . $e->getMessage();
    logError($message, $xmlFile);
    die("$message");
}

?>

